# I am getting this error: TypeError: store.getState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting the error :'TypeError: store.getState is not a function' and I can't determine where the problem is

here's how I created the store:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

const initialState = {
  pending: false,
  products: [],
  error: null
}
const middlewares = [thunk];

export const store=createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```

and here's the index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from './App'

import App from "./App";
  ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
  
      
        <App />
        
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and here's the thunk function:

```
function fetchProducts() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchProductsPending());
        fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches')
        .then(res => res.json()
        
        )
        .then(
          res => {
            if(res.error) {
                throw(res.error);
            }
            dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(res.products));
            return res.products;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(fetchProductsError(error));
        })
    }
}

export default fetchProducts;
```

and here's a sandbox of the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-sunset-wxefc?file=/src/index.js

here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Please post text as text, not images of text. Images are difficult on mobile, and impossible for screen readers.

Comment: @DaveNewton same error is available in the sandbox

Comment: Questions need to stand on their own, and have text posted as text, not images, for the stated reasons. Please see the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `store` is not the `default` export from the `./App.jsx` module. You either need to add curly braces to your import or export `store` as the `default`:

```js
// App.jsx

export const store = /* ... */

// index.js
import { store } from './App';
```

or

```js
// App.jsx

export default const store = /* ... */

// index.js
import store from './App';
```